# Pusher - Private channel subscription

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

I have a code with subscribe private channels, and when I try make a subscription I have the next message:

Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404

**Scenario:**

Javascript(Sencha touch) and PHP(Laravel)

*The subscription is in javascript:*

```
    Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = "/pusher.php";

    var APP_KEY = '4324523452435234523';
    var pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY);
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-l2');
    channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function() {
      alert("ahora siiii");
    });

    // for debugging purposes. Not required.
    Pusher.log = function(msg) {
      if(window.console && window.console.log) {
        window.console.log("PUSHER LOG: "+msg);
      }  
    }
```

*AND the pusher.php / LARAVEL*

```
    $this->app_id = '66981';
    $this->app_key = '4324523452435234523';
    $this->app_secret = 'f34632459911e2670dcf';

   $pusher = new Pusher($this->app_key, $this->app_secret, $this->app_id);
    $auth    = $pusher->socket_auth(Input::get('channel_name'), Input::get('socket_id'));

    echo $auth;
```

*The result is the error:*

```
     Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected
     Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404
```

Comment: I found my fall. I have needed make a login in my server for get the AUTH of pusher function. FIXED!!!!!

Comment: Any chance you could explain the answer a little more? If you remember (I know it was a while ago)

Answer (score 3):

You should set up a route for the Pusher authentication
`Route::post('pusher/auth', 'ApiController@pusherAuth');`

In that method you should first disable php debugbar (if you're using it) authenticate the user and if authentication checks, then return the response.

I'll paste my controller code below.

```
public function pusherAuth()
{
    \Debugbar::disable();
    $user = auth()->user();

    if ($user) {
        $pusher = new \Pusher(config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id'));
        echo $pusher->socket_auth(request()->input('channel_name'), request()->input('socket_id'));
        return;
    }else {
        header('', true, 403);
        echo "Forbidden";
        return;
    }
}
```

My JS code:

```
        var pusher = new Pusher(project.pusherKey, {
            cluster: 'eu',
            encrypted: true,
            authEndpoint: apiUrl(['pusher', 'auth']), // just a helper method to create a link
            auth: {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': project.token // CSRF token
                }
            }
        });

        var channelName =  'private-notifications-' + project.userId; // channel for the user id
        var channel = pusher.subscribe(channelName);

        channel.bind('new_notification', function (data)
        {
            app.addNotification(data); // send the notification in the JS app
        });
```

I hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Private Pusher channels require the client to authenticate for access. See http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users for details on [configuring the client for authentication](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#authEndpoint) and [setting up an authentication endpoint](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_endpoints).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = "/pusher.php";
```

for:

```
Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = "/public/broadcasting/auth";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert at laravel but I guess you have used get request to retrieve data(Socket id & channel name) while it's the post request from pusher server to your server endpoint. Use post to retrieve the data.